# Meta-analysis of different binnings of the same continuous variable

Tags: meta-analysis

I am conducting a meta-analysis in which household income is the IV. Unfortunately, for a variety of reasons, authors choose to operationalize income in a variety of ways. Some authors present associations with continuous income, but most choose somewhat arbitrary 'bins' with which to describe income, and then report cell counts (in the case of dichotomous outcomes) or mean/sd (in the case of continuous) within each income bin.

My question is how to handle this in the meta-analysis. Is it possible to either a) approximate a continuous effect based on the data I have or b) calculate a meaningful effect size between different ordinal scales.

I realize any solution I get to will be imperfect, it would just be nice not to have to throw out all these effects.

Comment: Unless you have additional information which you can use to "fix" your data it is not possible to do this. You could just jitter your data to add a little noise to it, but that's about it.

Comment: You can create a crude meta-analysis with a yes/no vote counting feature. The problem is variance. You might use this sample size, as a crude approximation.